# Is there a site that focuses on science?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a physics-, chemistry-, biology- or maybe mathematics-oriented Stack Exchange site?

Comment: @BalusC: SE has turned into what you see on Area51.  "Third Party" SE sites have been deprecated.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/migration-of-se-1-0-sites/

Comment: @squillman: ah yes, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an ever changing list that is a duplicate of [the science site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science-questionsperday).

Comment: I think the very good answer here is that link. And therefore should not be off-topic pretty much your answer covers it already sufficiently doesn't it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is [a full list of science sites on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-name)

Here are some examples from the [overview of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/): research-level mathematics.
- [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com): all levels of mathematics
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com)
- [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com)

There may be others as well. Check out the full list of sites for an up-to-date list.

Comment: Still, all these are sites for a particular domain within science, none of them deals with the fundamentals of the scientific process.

Comment: @Alex but everything is science, so how could u make a specific site for it:">"?

Comment: @bluejayke Everything is application of science, but not about the scientific process itself. It's like saying that everything in life is math, but nevertheless not useful at all to describe biology.stackexchange.com as being about math.

Comment: @bluejayke I mean, contrary to some popular belief, science is not the acquired knowledge itself. Science is the *process of acquiring* knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

**To update the existing answers for SE 2.0, Stacks in scientific fields now include**:

- [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com)
- [Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com)
- [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com)
- [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)
- [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com)
- [Statistics](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

These along with some other Stacks are listed in the Stack Exchange Directory under [**science**](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science) and new sites are being proposed in the [Area 51 science category](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science).

Answer (score 5):

Proposals at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) for SE-2.0 sites:

- [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) - [graduated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Chemistry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry?referrer=BOKvI_bZodgN5QfMOt5KEg2) - [graduated](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)
- <del>[Popular Natural Sciences](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4955/popular-natural-science?referrer=nwBIGRh-wRAN5QfMOt5KEg2)</del> - Proposal removed
- [Astronomy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy) - [public beta](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)

Your support in bringing them into existence is appreciated!

Comment: @AlE. are you *sure* about that [Astronomy](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) one?  Though this does point out the problem with external resources.

Comment: @MichaelT: Follow the link to Area 51. Right in the header at the top it says _"The Astronomy site didn't have enough activity during the beta. It has been closed, and its content has been merged into Physics. You can download the data dump of all questions here."_

Comment: @AlE. and that proposal was merged. And then it was restarted.  And it seems to be doing reasonably now. And this information is perpetually getting out of date.

Comment: _This_ particular answer seems to have been superceded by others, so it should probably be removed.

Comment: @AlE. That's never been the correct procedure - either answers are updated (which is ultimately the reason why everyone with sufficient reputation can do it, especially if the OP moved on) or the superseding answers (should) get more upvotes. Thanks for your updating this answer btw :)

Comment: @AlE. I agree with your close-vote though, there is no reason to maintain this question now that SE has an automatically up-to-date list

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know something about **scientific processes** like teaching, paper writing / reviewing, ethics, ... then you might want to have a look at [academia.stackexchange.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Although that is a site about the process of learning and reporting science, not the scientific process itself.